# Horizontal Stacked Bar with Gaps

Tags: chart.js

I am looking into the chartjs tool to see what its capabilities are and if I can use it in my project.

I have the following example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wVqONp

I would like a user to input a range (Ex. data1 could have min=250, max=500) and for that block to be added to the correct place on the x axis.  Unlike the example, there may be gaps between the bars. (Ex. data1 could have min=250,max=500 and data2 could have min=700,max=800).  I prefer overlaps to be allowable but if not that's ok. (Ex. data1 could have min=250,max=500 and data2 could have min=300,max=600). In other words, I would not want each data point to start at the minimum number, but instead be a range from min to max.

Is something like that possible?

Sorry but S.O. is requesting I put code in this post so I put a line of it below.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("Chart1");
```

UPDATE:

This is an upcoming feature in 2.9.0
https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4863

Codepen has been updated to show a working example using the development branch

Answer (score 0):

I updated the codepen to use the development branch of 2.9.0 with a min/max range and it now works as expected. This post can be considered closed.